# What is the difference between "how much gold this ring has?" and "how much gold do this ring has?"?

Tags: questions, interrogatives

What is the difference between the two sentences:

> 1. How much gold this ring has?
> 2. How much gold does this ring has?

Another example:

> 1. How much water do you have?
> 2. How much water you have?

## Update

I have two questions.

> How much something (do/does) something (have/has)?

When can I use *do/does*?

As you know this sentence:

> How much contrast your image has?

Here we neither use *do* nor *does*.

Comment: If you are confused about turning 'has' sentences into a question. Use 'does+have' in all those. This will work. So, How much gold does this ring have?; How much contrast does your image have? and so on... Hope this helps.

Comment: @gmotree, check my updated answer.

Comment: Note that you are asking 'difference between **sentences**' and you are posting 'questions'. Even further, 'how much gold this ring **has**' is **absolutely** fine but then it'd make a sentence and **not** a question. Like - How much money will I get by selling this off? ~ It all depends on **how much gold this ring has**. So, decide by yourself. If you are making a sentence without a question mark, the first example is fine, but as a question, it fails.

Answer (score 3):

Both examples are wrong grammatically. You need to ask,

> "How much gold does this ring have?"

**does** is the right word to use here and not **do** because your verb has to *agree* with the subject.

Since your subject is the *ring*, the correct verb to use is **does**.

Refer [this link](http://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/verbs/do-does-did/) for more examples and explanation.

**EDIT**

Based on OP's updated second question, am making an edit here.

Remember this basic rule

> Subjects and verbs must AGREE with one another in number (singular or
> plural).  Thus, if a subject is singular, its verb must also be
> singular; if a subject is plural, its verb must also be plural.
>
> **Do** matches all plurals as well as the singular subjects **I** and **you**.
> **Does** is for all other singular subjects. That’s the system for most
> present tense questions.
>
> Similarly, the verb do appears as does if the subject is a singular
> noun or, once again, a third-person singular pronoun (he, she, it):
>
> *Gus does the housework.*
>
> If the subject is a plural noun or the pronoun
>
> I, you, we, or they, use do:
>
> *Gus and Merdine do the chores together.*

[Source](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/subjectverb-agreement-in-questions.html)

[Source](http://grammar.about.com/od/correctingerrors/a/SpecSVA.htm)

Comment: How about "how much water do you have?" And " how much water you have" ?

Comment: What exactly do you want to ask the person regarding water? Consumption? Or availability?

Comment: I want to know an availability

Comment: Then you can ask, "How much water is available with you?" Personally, I'd prefer "What is the quantity of water you have available?"

Comment: Mamta, I think there's nothing wrong with "How much water do you have?" in the sense of availability.

Comment: Conversationally (at a casual level), it would be ok but if you're including it in some communication or article, then it wouldn't be proper.

Comment: Sir if you would mind, would you let me know what when we can use (do/does)? As you saw the last sentence, this How much contrast your image has? Is not used do or does. How can remove it?

Comment: **How much contrast your image has** is wrong grammatically. It should be **How much contrast**  *does* **your image** *have*? Please refer the links shared earlier to understand when to use **do** or **does**.

Comment: @MamtaD isn't *does* used as a 3rd person sing irrespective of the subject?

Comment: Yes, and that's mentioned in the answer already.

Comment: Sir, I am just qurious about why it is not proper just like using as casual?

Comment: @gmotree, Don't use "Sir". Can you please join the chat room to discuss this in detail? Long comment threads are to be avoided. Join here: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22937/ells-cabin

Comment: I am sure that this sentence doesn't make any sense "what's the quantity of water you have available?" This is plain wrong. Mamata, I am sure you're already aware of it. I think it's there just because you can't edit your comment :-)

Comment: Editing comments is perfectly possible. The sentence is not wrong at all. Say, if I visited a store and wanted to buy large amounts of water, this is exactly what I would ask. Too many comments for 1 answer are to be avoided as per ELL policy hence I invited him to chat.